# Can't run: The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

Tags: java, path

When I try to run my program it gives this error:

> The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

The environment variables should be set correctly.

Comment: Do you actually have an executable at `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`?

Comment: i have java.symlink, javaw.symlink and javaws.symlink in that folder

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the program isn't following your symlinks. You need make sure that:

1. The `java.exe` file is in that folder, or...
2. Change your environment variables (e.g. `PATH` and/or `JAVA_HOME`) such that they point to the folder where the `java.exe` file exists.